# Changing version number of my app in PhonegapBuild

Tags: xml, cordova

i am having trouble changing the version (of my app) and the phone gap version number in my config.xml. every time i do,ii get ann error of malformed config.xml

AppLoader gives me an error that my version number (i have a new app version now with push notification.  All I want to do is swap out binaries) isn’t right

when i change the version number here: (and it is the ONLY change I make)

```
version=”1.0.0″ xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets” xmlns:gap=”http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0″>
```

to

```
version=”1.2.0″ xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets” xmlns:gap=”http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0″>
```

PGB tells me the config.xml file is malformed.

HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Would adding "<" help?

```
<version=”1.2.0″ xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets” xmlns:gap=”http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0″>
```

Also, sometimes " marks are incorrect. Maybe, re-doing with all new quote marks will fix?